# Select and Copy all the modified lines in a File in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, text

I have done quite a lot of changes in a file and I am being asked to provide a summarized list of changes. Even if the files are already highlighted via git, I don't want to go through the whole file and copy paste each and every single line.

Is there a way to do this in VS Code?

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal run the command:

`git diff >changed.txt`